# How can I see my my calculated field from model in the drop down that was dynamically generated with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

In  models I have calculated field  `total`

And I want to see this field  in my dynamic drop boxes generated with Ajax.
But I just get undefined  in dropdown.

My data flows in following way:

1-I have sterilizer in my api

```
class LeaseTermSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=LeaseTerm       
    fields = '__all__'
```

2-I have api method in view

```
@api_view(['GET']) @csrf_exempt def get_leaseterm(request, tid):
    leasetermobj = LeaseTerm.objects.filter(lease=tid,is_active = True)
    leaseterm_serializer = LeaseTermSerializer(leasetermobj, many=True)
    response = Response(leaseterm_serializer.data)
    return Response(response.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

3-In my template I build it like this

```
function getleaseterm() {

    //get a reference to the select element
    $select = $('#leaseterm');
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    var l_id = ($("select[name='lease'] option:selected").attr('value'));
    l_url = "/api/get_leaseterm/"+l_id+"/";

    $.ajax({
      url: l_url,
      dataType:'JSON',
      success:function(data1){
        //clear the current content of the select
        $select.empty();
        $select.append('<option value="-1">Select term </option>');
        //iterate over the data and append a select option

        $.each(data1, function(key, val){
          $select.append('<option value="' + val.id  + '">' + val.id +  val.total + '</option>');
        })
      },

    });

}
```

How can I see my my calculated field from model in the drop down that was dynamically  generated with Ajax?

Comment: Maybe you should check the client's request return values that from the server contains the right data.

Comment: Can you add your response here

Comment: `' + val +  val.total + '` doesn't make a lot of sense. You want to print the whole variable, followed by one property of it? I doubt that is what you really intended. If you're getting "undefined" printed instead, then presumably `val` or one of its properties does not exist. Any errors in your browser console? Show us what the JSON in `data1` looks like, please. That would help a lot.

Comment: the problem is on Django backend  side I am sure about it . It is related to some steps I have to do with sterilizers . It looks like after sterilizing I get just the DB values and not the calculated fields.